# CoreData only saving most recently inserted object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to save data associated with pins that are added to a map. Each time a user adds a pin to a map, I want the lat, long, and title of the pin to be saved. Here's my savePin() function:

```
func savePin(location: BibleLocation) {

    let newPin = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Pin", into: context!) as! Pin
    newPin.setValue(location.lat, forKey: "lat")
    newPin.setValue(location.long, forKey: "long")
    newPin.setValue(location.name, forKey: "title")
    newPin.setValue(currentBook, forKey: "pinToBook")
    pinsForBook.append(newPin)

    appDelegate.saveContext()

}
```

The problem is that only the most recent pin inserted is returned by a fetch request:

```
func getPinsForGlossary() {

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Pin> = Pin.fetchRequest()
    let p = NSPredicate(format: "pinToBook = %@", currentBook!)
    request.predicate = p

    pinsForBook = []
    do {
        let results = try context!.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
        pinsForBook = results as! [Pin]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I don't think I'm overwriting data when I call insertNewObject. Why is only the most recent inserted object being saved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the relationship between your objects in Core Data graph

Comment: I guess you have a one-to-one relationship, so when you set `currentBook` as `pinToBook` of one object, it is automatically set to `nil` in the previous one.

Comment: That was it! I thought I had set the relationships up already, but I hadn't Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a **one-to-one** relationship, so when you set `currentBook` as `pinToBook` of one object, it is automatically set to `nil` in the previous one.

If that's your case, you should set relationship to **one-to-many**, so that one book can be used in multiple `Pin` objects as `pinToBook` value.